# Is there a Web Service community with a large and variety pool of services provided to consume?

Tags: wcf, rest, service

Please specify and rate your experience if you know any. Thanks! =]

Answer (score 1):

No there wouldn't be anything like that. In my experience each web service is designed for a very specific purpose, and would not have application outside it's original product. Also, a lot of web services are locked down to prevent unauthorized access. I am not aware of any collection of web services being made available from a single place. Would be curious to check it out if there is one, though.

Plamen

Comment: Thx, for my own experience, I haven't encountered any too, and that's why I am curious to find out. I am asking this partly for a research I am working on.